# Understanding Daily Summary for Fabric

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

In daily summary mail recieved from fabric, I am unable to see my some of the apps as i recieved only 10 app summary in mail.
But in my account i have 122 apps which includes beta, dev and market builds for different apps.

Is there any limit on number of apps shown in Daily summary report from fabric?

I tried to search the fabric site for any kind of documentation on daily summary or limiting the number of app in summary.

Expected - Official confirmation on number of app showing in daily summary on Mail Not on fabric site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the daily summary email is limited to 10 apps.